# How to format Sharepoint List to add link on top of image

Tags: json, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I would like to edit sharepoint list to display Image, and hyper link to another site (eventually, make Image to be clickable - once clicked it will move user to other page)[Something like on this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkHpa.png)

I manage to format list to display the picture like below, however I am not able to add hyper link or make it clickable

[current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fF3vK.png)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/tile-formatting.schema.json",
  "hideSelection": true,
  "width": "355",
  "height": "355",
  "formatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "style": {
          "display": "inline-block",
          "min-width": "355px",
          "min-height": "355px",
          "margin-right": "10px",
          "box-shadow": "2px 2px 4px darkgrey"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "img",
            "attributes": {
              "src": "[$Image.serverRelativeUrl]"
            },
            "style": {
              "height": "360px",
              "max-width": "360px"
            }
          },
      {
        "elmType": "a",
        "txtContent": "Click here",
        "style": {
          "border": "none",
          "padding-top": "0px",
          "color": "#0078d7",
          "padding-left": "0px",
          "text-align": "center",
          "cursor": "pointer"
            },
            "attributes": {
              "target": "_blank",
              "href": "[$Link]"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

i went through documentation but nothing helps

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try this JSON:

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/tile-formatting.schema.json",
  "hideSelection": true,
  "width": "355",
  "height": "355",
  "formatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "style": {
          "display": "inline-block",
          "min-width": "355px",
          "min-height": "355px",
          "margin-right": "10px",
          "box-shadow": "2px 2px 4px darkgrey"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "a",
            "attributes": {
              "target": "_blank",
              "href": "[$Link]"
            },
            "children": [
              {
            "elmType": "img",
            "attributes": {
              "src": "[$Image.serverRelativeUrl]"
            },
            "style": {
              "height": "360px",
              "max-width": "360px"
            }
          }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is the result in my side:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1Efc.png)